# CSS transition not working on submenu on hover

Tags: html, css

I have a menu with submenu working fine, however I am trying to add css transition on sub menu, If I mouseover on second nav item, the submenu which appear should have slide from top to bottom transition but its not working, can anybody please suggest?

Here is the working [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/xwx5dwgd/)

```css
.header_right {
float: right;
width: 100%;
min-height: 80px;
line-height: 80px;
}
.header_right > ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-size: 0;
text-align: right;
}
.header_right > ul > li {
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
background: #3275a6;
padding: 8px 16px;
color: #fff;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: normal;
vertical-align: middle;
transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;
}
.header_right > ul > li > a {
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
}
.header_right > ul > li:nth-child(1) {
margin-right: 15px;
cursor: default;
}
.header_right > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a {
cursor: default;
}
.header_right > ul > li:hover {
background: #14507d;
}
.header_right > ul > li.actbtn {
background: #14507d;
}
.navigation-third {
background: #14507d;
border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
display: none;
list-style: outside none none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 33px;
width: 100%;
-moz-transition: top 0.7s, right 0.7s, bottom 0.7s, left 0.7s;
-webkit-transition: top 0.7s, right 0.7s, bottom 0.7s, left 0.7s;
transition: top 0.7s, right 0.7s, bottom 0.7s, left 0.7s;
}
.navigation-third > li {
list-style: outside none none;
}
.navigation-third > li > a {
color: #fff;
font-size: 14px;
padding: 10px 12px;
display: block;
text-align: left;
text-decoration: none;
}
.navigation-third > li > a:hover {
background-color: #0076AA;
}
.navigation-third > li:nth-child(2) > a:hover {
border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}
.header_right > ul > li:nth-child(2):hover .navigation-third {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header_right">
  <ul>
    <li href="javascript:;"><i class="ico ico_location"></i> <a href="javascript:;">Delhi/NCR</a> </li>
    <li> <a class="sub-3"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>&nbsp; Welcome,  User</a>
      <ul class="navigation-third">
        <li><a href="javascript:;" class=""><i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i> User Account</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;" class=""><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: To get desired effect you should use another property, height: https://jsfiddle.net/xwx5dwgd/4/ but, since you don't know exact height and can't set it (i have used 74 px in demo, and it works fine, because fixed height is set), maybe jquery is better option...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `display: none` to do this. Use CSS's `visibility` property instead. Also, since you're using transition for `top` (plus a few more) property, you also have to use a varying `top` value.

That being said, your CSS should look like this:

```
.navigation-third {
    background: #14507d;
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    visibility: hidden; <-- Changed
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;             <-- Changed
    width: 100%;
    -moz-transition: top 0.7s, right 0.7s, bottom 0.7s, left 0.7s;
    -webkit-transition: top 0.7s, right 0.7s, bottom 0.7s, left 0.7s;
    transition: top 0.7s, right 0.7s, bottom 0.7s, left 0.7s;
}

.header_right > ul > li:nth-child(2):hover .navigation-third {
  visibility: visible;  <-- Changed
  top: 33px;            <-- Added
}
```

Note: You still have to play a bit with `z-index` I guess, since this snippet places the dropdown in front of your nav item (doesn't look smooth). You may also play with the sliding transition. Just change your top values accordingly.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xwx5dwgd/2/)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want your CSS to transition between your positioning attributes on `.navigation-third` when hovering on its parent element?

If so, it doesn't work because the only thing happening right now on hover is that the display property is changed. There's no other position for it to transition between.

A solution is to add your "default" position when the list is hidden and then your "correct" positioning values when hovering.

Also, in this scenario (if you want to avoid JavaScript) you want to transition between the element's `opacity` value rather than its `display` value when you want to show/hide it, since CSS cannot transition between `display` properties. An important thing to add to this implementation is `pointer-events: none` when the element is hidden to avoid accidental clicks or hovers.

Answer (score 1):

You cant use transition on display property. You can simply achieve this by using jquery. here is example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xwx5dwgd/3/).

```
$('#sec').hover( function(){
       $('.navigation-third').stop().slideToggle('slow');   
    });
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Why did you use stop() in there? It works otherwise also.

Comment: If I hover in and out multiple times in a quickly(say 3 times in a 2sec). The animation will happen 3 times after the mouse move away. To see this remove the stop() from code and hover in and out in quick time.